# How can I get the text and its format from clipboard at the same time?

Tags: c#

[image]

This is the text I want to copy on a page in the browser. I tried to use `Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html)` to get the HTML in order to get the text and keep the format at the same time, but the `InnerText` turned to `简述?Func&amplt;T&ampgt;与?Action&amplt;T&ampgt;的区别`. I can replace the escape characters by the characters they represent, but I don't know what original character the '?' was because I'm going to deal with huge information by code and it's meaningless if I have to check every sentence.

I also try this

```cs
string text = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html);
byte[] data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text);
text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

came out the same result.

And `GetClipboardData(uint uFormat)` in 'user32.dll' which not gonna help.

I actually could get the correct text `简述 Func<T>与 Action<T>的区别` by using `Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.UnicodeText)`, but it will lose the style.

There has to be a way I can get the text and the format at the same time because the docx or some other software can display the text in the correct format when you paste on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text you are seeing is the actual string as it is in the web page before the browser interprets it. To convert those special sequences like `&amplt;`, use HtmlDecode. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Yeah, it solved the problem. And I found out the reason why the space change to '?' is I displayed the html string on Console and the default encoding is `System.Text.DBCSCodePageEncoding`. When I set it to the `UTF8`, it showed the right string. Anyway, thanks.